# How can I listen for mouse wheel events in the Margin between two items in an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouse, margin

I have an `ItemsControl` that looks something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" PreviewMouseWheel="ItemsControl_PreviewMouseWheel" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,4"><!--Margin to keep the items from being smashed too closely together-->
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `ItemsControl` will be one of several items in a scrollable area, but if I use the mouse wheel over the `ItemsControl`, nothing happens. So I want to forward the mouse wheel events further up the tree:

```
private void ItemsControl_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    RaiseEvent(new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
    {
        RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent
    });
}
```

This mostly works. But when the mouse scrolls over the `Margin` area (specified by `Margin="0,4"`) between two items in the control, nothing happens. I tried putting the grid inside a decorator, such as a `Border`, but that doesn't seem to help. How can I capture these mouse wheel events, and forward them up the tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Margin is the area of space left around a Control, and since it's just empty space it doesn't process any events.

An alternative is to either nest controls, such as putting your Grid with the Margin inside a DockPanel without a Margin, or to use a WPF control that has the `Padding` property such as Border

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in my question, this solution does not work--scrolling over the empty space still does nothing.

Comment: @Matthew How did you test it earlier? If you used a border, did you specify a background color? I believe the default background is transparent, which lets events pass through the control.

Comment: Ah, I just had to set the background. Setting it to `Transparent` is fine, but not setting it lets events pass through the control. Thanks!